# Sending multiple images using Lotus Traveler mail

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My customer wants me to send an email with multiple image attachments, company policy requires the use of lotus notes traveler 8.5.3.

The problem is that I can not send an email with attachments using lotus notes. The gmail and samsung e-mail apps do not have any issues with sending e-mails with multiple images attached using the code below.

Is use the following C# (monodroid) code to create an intent for sending emails

```
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ActionSendMultiple);
    intent.SetType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new String[] {emailAddress});
    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, mail.Subject);
    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText,  Html.FromHtml( mail.MailBody));
    List<IParcelable> paths = getPhotoPaths();
    if (paths.Count >0){
        intent.PutParcelableArrayListExtra (Intent.ExtraStream,paths);
    }
    StartActivity(intent);
```

Can someone tell me why lotus traveler does not handle this intent?

Thanks,

Tjeerd

Comment: When you contacted Lotus and asked them that question, what did they tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traveler doesn't support the send_multiple action.
I'll open a requirement for a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we found a workaround, hope this will help others.

To send multiple images, we bundle them in a zip file. Then you can use the normal ActionSend intent to send this zip file whit the email

Like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ActionSend);
intent.SetType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new String[] {emailAddress});
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, mail.Subject);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText,  Html.FromHtml(mail.MailBody));
intent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(zippedFilePath));
StartActivity(intent);
```